# React Native: Build APK that can connect to development server

Tags: android, react-native

I have an interesting scenario. It was an `expo` project that I converted to `react-native`. I don't have a `react-native` command (but can run `npx react-native`, but my understanding is to build the test APK I run `yarn android` which actually runs `expo run:android`.

However, my dev server is remote, so I'm looking to generate an APK and then use the developer menu to set the IP address of the dev server on the device, then connect to the react native server (i.e. not using Expo anymore)

How do I go about building this APK? When I use `yarn android` it says there are no devices connected and won't build.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`npx react-native run-android` builds an APK in `./android/app/build/outputs/apk` but then fails. Just install this APK, then run it, shake the device to get the menu to pop up (or Cntrl-M for the menu on an emulator), settings, and dev server info is there (port 8081 default).